# How do i count strings as a number in R

Tags: r, string

Good day,

I am a beginner to R and I'm trying to add up some strings from multiple values.
I got 2 values for an example;

```
NominationsGrammyAwards <- c("Grammy Award For best Videoclip", "Song of the Year", "Best Rap Performance", "Best Rap Song", "Best Music Video")

NominationBETAward <- "Video Of The Year"
```

that's a total of 6 strings, but how do I get it in just a number 6. For example, I want to add those together in a value called TotalNominations. Like this:

```
TotalNominations <- (Which code?)
```

I tried something with sapply but that didn't work. Who can help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `length`:

```r
NominationsGrammyAwards <- c("Grammy Award For best Videoclip", "Song of the Year", "Best Rap Performance", "Best Rap Song", "Best Music Video")

NominationBETAward <- "Video Of The Year"

length(NominationsGrammyAwards)
#> [1] 5

length(NominationBETAward)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Edit 1 to add them:

```r
a <- NominationsGrammyAwards <- c("Grammy Award For best Videoclip", "Song of the Year", "Best Rap Performance", "Best Rap Song", "Best Music Video")

b <- NominationBETAward <- "Video Of The Year"

length(a) + length(b)
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That works, but how do i add this together, to get them to 6 total, in like TotalNominations

Comment: See Edit 1 to add them.